# Checking a checkbox in a list, based on the textcontent of the list item

Tags: jquery

I've got a list that looks like this:

```
<ul id="someList">
    <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="1" /> One </li>
    <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="2" /> Two </li>
    <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="3" /> Three </li>
</ul>
```

I was trying to use jQuery to find the li that contains specific text and then check the corresponding checkbox.  Something like this:

```
        $("#someList").find("Two").prev("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
```

Well I couldn't get that to work.  So after some searching, I found an example using filter() that DID work.

```
     $('li').filter(function(){
             var txt = this.textContent;
             return txt === 'Two';  
         }).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

That works like a champ.  The only problem is, it seems more complicated than I expected.

My question is fairly simple.  Is this the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `find("Two")` would find elements with the _tag name_ `Two`, it has nothing whatsoever to do with the elements contents. You rather want https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to find the `li` by its content, and then use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `input`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#someList li:contains('Two')").find("input").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someList">
    <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="1" /> One </li>
    <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="2" /> Two </li>
    <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="3" /> Three </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use `children()` to get `input checkbox` and check.

1. `$("#someList li:contains('Two')")` would get the `li` element.
2. `children("input")` would get the checkbox element inside `li`.
3. `prop("checked", true)` would check the checkbox element.

```js
$("#someList li:contains('Two')").children("input").prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someList">
 <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="1" /> One </li>
 <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="2" /> Two </li>
 <li><input name="myNumber" type="checkbox" value="3" /> Three </li>
</ul>
```